# Undefined index error in a variable

Tags: php, cart

My website is [Career Tracker](http://careertracker.net/)
i want to add cart in my website in my local machine i got a error everytime so i tired.

i used XAMPP 1.8.1 [PHP: 5.4.7] i got a error everytime
Notice: Undefined index: cart in functions.inc.php on line 4

i tired why my php veriable is undefined ?? $cart

this is my code i got error in 4 the line.

php undefined index error

```
    <?php
function writeShoppingCart() 
{   
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (!$cart) 
    {
        return 'My Cart (0) Items';
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Parse the cart session variable
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
        return '<a href="cart.php">'.count($items).' item'.$s.' in your cart</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try @$_SESSION['cart'] instead of $_SESSION['cart']; on line number 3

Comment: @user1640432 Never use the @ to suppress errors

Comment: i already added session start in my header.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check whether cart index exists or not.

```
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();
```

Comment: after changed this line error is clear but output is changed and

Comment: i got all the php code in my html page like 


`code'
function showCart() { global $db; $cart = $_SESSION['cart']; if ($cart) { $items = explode(',',$cart); $contents = array(); foreach ($items as $item) { $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1; } $output[] = ''; $output[] = ''; foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) { $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '.$id; $result = $db->query($sql); $row = $result->fetch(); extract($row); $output[] = ''; $total += $prince * $qty; $output[] = ''; } $output[] = '`code`

i got this query in my html page

Comment: @Savan Either you have an end tag `?>` or you are not using the correct extension.

Comment: It's not about changed line. You may forget to put `<?PHP` or `?>` tags

Comment: Thank you
oozel and Deniel my error is clear and working good :)
thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your session does not contain any index by the name "cart"

To make sessions available over multiple pages you need to activate sessions before any output by using the `session_start` function.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a variable before you've set it will throw a Notice.

Try checking if it exists first using the `isset()` function.
Edited to note that you've also not started your session: `session_start()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: thanx @wren my error is clear but i got another problem that php print all the code in html file.

Comment: i used the 

$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : array();

Answer (score 0):

just change your code as: (i normaly use for this case)

```
<?php
function writeShoppingCart() 
{  
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{ 
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (!$cart) 
    {
        return 'My Cart (0) Items';
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Parse the cart session variable
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
        return '<a href="cart.php">'.count($items).' item'.$s.' in your cart</a></p>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

may this help you...